# Wordpress updating screen_layout_post user meta for 1 column layout

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get Wordpress to show a 1 column layout when adding a new post using the following code in my functions file.

```
function wpsnippy_one_columns_posts_layout( $columns ) {
    $columns['vehicle'] = 1;
    return $columns; } add_filter( 'screen_layout_columns', 'wpsnippy_one_columns_posts_layout' );   function wpsnippy_screen_layout_posts() {
    return 1; } add_filter( 'get_user_option_screen_layout_post', 'wpsnippy_screen_layout_posts' );
```

This is working fine if logged in as admin, however I have a user type 'seller' and it is not working for seller, I actually need it to be the other way around, 1 column if seller 2 if anything else.

Your input will be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can [filter the function `get_user_option()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/user.php#L380) and force 1 column:

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_screen_layout_post', function( $result, $option, $user )
{
    if( in_array( 'seller', $user->roles ) )
        $result = '1';

    return $result;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Note that the option is defined like: `"screen_layout_$page"`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is still the same with your suggested code unfortunately I have changed the code (updated question) and this is working but not for sellers, when I now click on screen options the only option is a 1 column but it is not defaulting to that state.